# Do Almofire 4x ~> supports HTTP3?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, http3

I am doing a POC, has anyone has ever tried to consume HTTP/3.0 web server using Alamofire?
If yes, have you consumed it using QUIC?

Comment: Seems to be available only in iOS15+, and it's a parameter on `URLRequest`. You can add it yourself, since under the hood, Alamofire uses URLSession, URLRequest, etc. So I guess it should work, give it a try? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3102-http3-in-your-app

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be an issue because the webserver will produce the JSON in any way you want it via the API call.If it doesn't work yet, alamofire usually updates frequently and will have a patch soon.

If it doesn't work just use as Larme said : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/technotes/tn3102-http3-in-your-app